# Repeated steps Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

For the equation in cell `E717` it currently has `=IF(F717>=0,E716+G716*$B$5+((1/2)*L716*($B$5^2)),E716)`.

However, what I'm trying to do is if `F717>0` then use formula `*E716+G716*$B$5+((1/2)*L716*($B$5^2)),E716)*` BUT if `F717=0` then use the formula but for the following rows in `F` stay at this value (Stay at the value in `F1717`)

E.g for the picture shown ABOVE since `F717=0` then the value in `E717` will use the formula in this case it has the value `34.997` BUT for the row `E718` I want it to stay at `34.997` and for `E719` stay at `34.997` and so on. Almost as if since it hits the first zero in `F`, use the formula, stop, then keep at the value of `E717 (34.997)`.

e.g. I want it to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work for your situation.  It uses the previous value of `E` if the current and previous value in `F` is 0, otherwise it uses the formula.  The effect is it only uses the formula for values in `F>0` and when `F` first hits a `0`.

`=IF(AND(F716=0,F717=0),E716,E716+G716*$B$5+((1/2)*L716*($B$5^2)))`